# plotting in python until specific date with pie chart

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I need to plot in  python until specific given date. I have the twits of trump in given times and I need to do a pie chart before he got elected and after. I managed to do the after but not the before and I would like your help. Thank you.

This is what I have done so far:
[image: Plot]

[img src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKutI.png)

Comment: Have you tried replacing the "larger than" comparator `>` in the line `after=df[(df['created_at'] > '19-12-2016')]` to a "less than" comparator `<`?

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, Yas I have tried it. But I found other way to do so, thank you very much :)